# ngAfterViewInit local variables undefined angular 6

Tags: angular6

I am getting `this.objectsCount is undefined in addcomponent function`
what am I doing wrong? if I debug this has only "div,el,sidenav,subscription".

```
export class SidenavComponent implements OnInit {
subscription: Subscription;
tog: { compact: boolean, tag: string };
objectsCount: { tag: any, ctrl: Object }[];
compact: boolean;
tag: string;
@ViewChild('sidebar') div;
objects: any;
constructor(private sidenav: SidenavService, private el: ElementRef) {
}
ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = this.sidenav.onToggle().subscribe((toggle) => {
this.tog = toggle;
if (toggle.tag) {
  let nav = this.el.nativeElement;

  //nav.attributes.
 }
});
}
addcomponent(elem) {
 this.objectsCount.push({ tag: elem.nativeElement("tag").value, ctrl: 
 elem.nativeElement });
 }
 ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.addcomponent(this.div);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never initialize the objectsCount Array, set it in the OnInit function

```
  this.objectsCount = [];
```